# div se muestra al pulsar sobre botón pero no se oculta al pulsar sobre el mismo botón

Tags: javascript

Buenas,

Tengo un pequeño `div` en mi código en el que al pulsar sobre un elemento `<a>`se me abre un pequeño desplegable para iniciar sesión, pero quiero que al pulsar en ese mismo elemento, desaparezca. El caso es que no consigo hacer que esta segunda parte ocurra y no entiendo dónde tengo el error.

Código HTML:

```
 <div id="sesion_popup">
   <a href="#">Login avanzado</a>
   <a href="#">Registrarse</a>
   <div class="credenciales">
       <div class="inputs">
           <input type="text" name="" value="">
           <input type="password" name="" value="">
       </div>
    <input class="submit_login" type="submit" name="submit_login" value="►">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Por otra parte el código del fichero .js, es más extenso pero muestro sólo lo que es relevante a mi parecer:

```
$(document).ready(main);

var count = 0;

function main(){


$('#invitado').click(function(){
    if (count == 0) {
        document.getElementById('sesion_popup').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('invitado').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementsByClassName('inicio_registro').style.display = 'none';
        count = 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sesion_popup').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('invitado').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementsByClassName('inicio_registro').style.display = 'block';
        count = 0;
    }

})  
};
```

En teoría el valor de la variable `count` pasa de 0 cuando el div está oculto a 1 cuando sí que se muestra. Al pulsar de nuevo sobre el elemento con `id="invitado"` debería de pasar de nuevo al valor 0 y ocultarse, pero eso no ocurre.

También tengo un problema con la línea de código `document.getElementsByClassName('inicio_registro').style.display = 'none';` puesto que no me oculta los 2 elementos `<a>` de inicio de sesión y de registro.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: no veo el html del botón "invitado"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que (creo) interpreta tu caso de uso. Hay un elemento `a` que muestra u oculta la cada de login. Ésta parte oculta y el visitante sólo ve el link "invitado"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var count = 0;

  $('#invitado').click(function(){
      console.log(count);
      if (count == 0) {
          document.getElementById('sesion_popup').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('invitado').style.color = 'grey';
          count = 1;
      } else {
          document.getElementById('sesion_popup').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('invitado').style.color = 'black';
          count = 0;
      }

  });

});
```

```css
#sesion_popup {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="invitado">Invitado</a>

<div id="sesion_popup">
   <a href="#">Login avanzado</a>&nbsp;
   <a href="#">Registrarse</a>&nbsp;
   <div class="credenciales">
       <div class="inputs">
           <input type="text" name="" value="">
           <input type="password" name="" value="">
       </div>
    <input class="submit_login" type="submit" name="submit_login" value="►">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: En el clavo, me queda tan sólo quitar los elementos <a> que me siguen apareciendo cuando el div se muestra y no quiero que se muestren, pero si sigo con el problema abriré otra pregunta. Solucionado pues el problema de la pregunta principal. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si ya estás usando *jQuery* yo te recomiendo tener una clase que oculte tu elemento, por ejemplo:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Tu elemento con el id `inicio_registro` lo inicias con la clase:

```
<div id="inicio_registro" class="hidden">
```

... y en tu código de *Javascript*:

```
$('#invitado').click(function(){
    $('#sesion_popup,#invitado,#inicio_registro').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```